# DES. Weak Keys!

Tags: c++, c, des

I've been reading through the DES standard and part of the standard mentioned the bit parity & weak keys. So I've been wondering about the merits of weak keys and their side affects. Some example of weakly formed keys were represented in Hexadecimal format. So part of my assessment relating to weak keys that the repetition of the same 8bit/4bit/2bit groupings throughout a key are classifiable as weak keys! Are my conclusions correct?

Comment: You are aware that DES is considered broken for ages now and shouldn't be used at all anymore ? The alternative is 3DES but that is slow, so AES is the way to go now.

Comment: @DarkDust - You're correct, but it is actually a very good question for a learner. A great crypto algorithm is worthless if the users use keys that are weak. DES is a wonderful example of this (among others) pitfall. That is something to be aware of even if you don't use DES, to be sure to check the issue for the algorithms you do use.

Comment: I forgot to mention, that I know DES has been crippled. I'm building my own implementation of SSL/TLS library. (already wrote AES, now DES and now writing TDES) for backwards compatibility

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes. For example classic weak key is `0x0101010101010101`. Problem with the selected permutations. [Here is the detailed explanation.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weak_key)

Comment: So we agree my assumptions are correct! I was thinking of writing some check algorithm using different groupings check, but the standard also specifies the parity check. Odd number of 1s! Implementing that overall degree of strictness is it necessary? 0xFC32135003100880

Comment: @Nocturnal - you can just check the key against a list of weak keys, there aren't so many.